# Az Module problem: Get-AzConsumptionBudget returns 422 (unproccessable entity)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Reposting this on stackoverflow from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/answers/773301/view.html
because the microsoft QA website is broken and won't let me comment on my post.

---

Original:

I have a runbook that, since a couple of weeks, returns a 422 while getting a list of budgets in resource groups:

```
     $budgets = Get-AzConsumptionBudget -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
```

This returns a 422 on my test environment. On the acc and prd environment, no such error occurs. This also keeps triggering alerts in my mailbox so I want this fixed.
I ran this locally as well with fiddler, this is the raw request data:

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 216
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
session-id: 4d361bc3-d9c6-42a0-a62a-ce8284461cd7
x-ms-request-id: d6cd3373-bbb7-4bbc-8c8e-a99e2f998513
x-ms-correlation-id: d7f8b4d0-f23e-48b6-9109-75a22e6f00cf
x-ms-correlation-request-id: 885e3b11-2393-44a8-80a8-1ccd57318bd3
x-ms-client-request-id: d7d1f605-b216-4d1e-9429-2afe8906e7b1
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads: 11999
x-ms-routing-request-id: WESTEUROPE:20220224T084156Z:885e3b11-2393-44a8-80a8-1ccd57318bd3
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Thu, 24 Feb 2022 08:41:56 GMT

{"error":{"code":"422","message":"This operation is not supported in the version specified in the request. Please use version 2018-12-01-preview-preview or later. (Request ID: d6cd3373-bbb7-4bbc-8c8e-a99e2f998513)"}}
```

As you can see, something is outdated. I tried updating the Az modules in the automation account and Az.Billing specifically, but so far no success. I haven't found anyone with a similar problem.

What is happening?

The problem started appearing out of the blue february 1st. We weren't working on these systems and no changes were made in our Azure environment's configuration.

---

Update / Extra info:

So, this problem went from a nuisance to preventing me from testing certain functionality. I have looked everywhere yet I seem to be the only one with this problem.

I have tried the following:
Connected to our test environment locally, and then running Get-AzConsumptionBudget. Here we get the information in the original post. I have also noticed that it uses the following endpoint:

GET /subscriptions//providers/Microsoft.Consumption/budgets?api-version=2018-01-31 HTTP/1.1 -> note the api-version. The error message was "Please use version 2018-12-01-preview-preview or later." I would love to, but I'm stuck with whatever the PS module wants me to use..

If I connect to our client's acceptation environment, It uses the same endpoint but it does return the budgets as expected. It also has api-version=2018-01-31.

Now I checked the Azure Resource explorer to see if there were any differences in Microsoft.Consumption, there I found this in both environments:

```
"resourceType": "Budgets",
"locations": [],
"apiVersions": [
"2021-10-01",
"2019-10-01",
"2019-05-01",
"2019-04-01-preview",
"2019-03-01-preview",
"2019-01-01-preview",
"2019-01-01",
"2018-12-01-preview",
"2018-10-01",
"2018-08-31",
"2018-06-30",
"2018-03-31",
"2018-01-31",
"2017-12-30-preview"
]
```

This tells me both of them have 2018-01-31 as a supported version. As a final piece of info, the problems probably started from february 1st, showing up in our logs on february 2nd. I couldnt find any info on whether anything changed on the MS side of things, nothing changed on our side at least.

If anyone knows what's up with this, I'd love to know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Get-AzConsumptionBudget 422 error with CSP Azure Plan Subscription](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/17485)

Comment: Have you ever tried the answer and the suggestions. If the answer is helpful, please mark it as a correct one. If not, we are happy to help you solve the issue.

Comment: I haven't had the time yet due to commitments elsewhere. I suspect the solution to be correct anyway because our MS contact also suggested using the API.
Our Azure subscription admin also tried enabling the older API (Or something - I don't know the procedure) as he suggested should also work - that did not work however.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Please try the API anyhow to see if it can help you.

Comment: So, a little while ago I got around to it. The API works as expected however there was a slight difference in return values etc. (datetimes as strings for example)
Initially I feared I would have to rework a lot because the original code was written by a colleague and i didnt know the implications. However, I managed to get it to work with minimal rework after all.